# Can you export a visual studio application for mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2015, export, sdl-2

I'm coding a cross-platform game making sure to carefully use code that can run on both windows and mac. The game has been developed in visual studio 2015 in c++ and SDL2 and needs to be exported as a .app (or anything else that can run on mac), is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. You can get a feel for the amount of work involved by following this procedure:

1. Get a Mac.
2. Install developer tools on your Mac.
3. Copy your code to the Mac.
4. Create an Xcode project for your app.
5. Add all your source code files to your Xcode project.
6. Click Build.

You will find that you have many thousands of errors. You will need to rearchitect your app to isolate platform dependencies.

Or, you could google "port windows app to mac" and try a third-party solution.